# mysql multiple counts in a single query

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT SUM( CASE WHEN is_half = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) halfCount, SUM( CASE 
WHEN is_half = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) totalCount FROM employee_leave WHERE 
YEAR(leave_date_from) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) AND employee_id="EMP12" AND 
leave_status=1
```

With this query I am getting results as(If there are no values):

```
halfCount | totalCount
NULL      | NULL
```

How can I get 0 instead of NULL?

Desired output:

```
halfCount | totalCount
0         | 0
```

Comment: I think [`COALESCE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql) can help you

Comment: How can i use it with my query?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your query is correct, you can use COALESCE to change null into 0 *(or any other number)*

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM( CASE WHEN is_half = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ), 0) as 'halfCount',
COALESCE(SUM( CASE WHEN is_half = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ), 0) as 'totalCount'
FROM employee_leave
WHERE YEAR(leave_date_from) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()
     AND employee_id="EMP12"
     AND leave_status=1
```

I'm not really sure if this is error-free, as I can't test it in my machine, but that is how to use `COALESCE`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT IFNULL(SUM( CASE WHEN is_half = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ),0) halfCount, IFNULL(SUM( CASE 
WHEN is_half = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ),0) totalCount FROM employee_leave WHERE 
YEAR(leave_date_from) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) AND employee_id="EMP12" AND 
leave_status=1
```

Comment: also try " ISNULL ".

Comment: SELECT ISNULL(IFNULL(SUM( CASE WHEN is_half = 1 THEN 1 
    ELSE 0 END ),0),0) halfCount, ISNULL(IFNULL(SUM( CASE 
    WHEN is_half = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ),0),0) totalCount FROM 
    employee_leave WHERE 
    YEAR(leave_date_from) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) AND 
    employee_id="EMP12" AND 
    leave_status=1


Should i use it in this way?

@romal tandel